# Ajax page load with <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an a-tag which when clicked, page gets reloaded and certain php code is executed. On successful execution of php code the page is then redirected to same page.

Now, the problem is that the page is jumping to the top which I guess is normal unless you don't use ajax. So, if I can get some assistance with the lines of codes below.

html:

```
<a href="home.php?key=some_value&val=1" id="ajax_reload">Unfollow</a>
```

on clicking the above link this php code is executed

php:

```
if(isset($_GET['key']) && isset($_GET['val'])){
            //some task....
            header('location:home.php'); 
        }
```

NOTE: all codes are is same page home.php
if I can do this without reloading the entire page that would really be helpful.

[Edit] I am really sorry to not have added this in my question. I am using php to show bunch of datas on my page from mysql database. hence all datas have same id and class

Comment: Do you want to explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: If you're in home.php, why are you redirecting to home.php after the if statement tasks have finished? If you want an action to be performed without the page reloading, you'll have to use Ajax

Comment: @WillParky93 this is because in that if statements I am making certain changes which will effect how my pages looks. to make that changes on my page. I am reloading it. so that changes shows in the HTML.

Comment: @Companjo I wish I could but It's a bit complex to explain what I am trying to achieve but this is what I wish to do. Thanks for showing interest in my question. I wish to get help from this community. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this via ajax

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ajax_reload" data-key="some_value" data-someval="1">Unfollow</a>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.ajax_reload').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
                 url : home.php,
                 type:'POST',
                 data : {key: $(this).data('key'), val:$(this).data('someval')},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data.success==1)
                   location.reload();
                }
            });
    });
```

});

```
</script>
```

in home .php

```
if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['val'])){
            //some task....
           echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));exit();
       }
```

It may contain some syntax errors it is basic idea how to use it via ajax

Comment: links are no longer clickable.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? and also try to alert in the function   `$('#ajax_reload').on('click',function(){`

Comment: here were few errors like url was missing inverted comas. then coma at the end of dataType: 'json' apart from it could find anything

Comment: I am getting this error in console 'Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead'

Comment: No I need a little help. actually I am not all the experianced. so how do I fix the above error?

Comment: where are you using this getPreventDefault()? use event.preventDefault(); instead of getPreventDefault().

Comment: I have made some changes in my code , let me know if you ran into any issues.thanks

Comment: I am not using getPreventDefault() anywhere in my page.

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using? try to use the latest one.

Comment: I cannot spot any changes. I am sorry. And once I am very grateful for you help and time. :)

Comment: I have made changes in php file, I have used $_POST instead of $_GET because we are using type :post in ajax.

Comment: I have updated it to latest version still same error - Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Can you try to run into chrome for once ? as this error likely occurs when you are using the old version of FF and jquery

Comment: Okay so now on clicking the link the changes that I had to make in database is happening but it's not showing in my html unless I refresh the page.

Comment: I guess that is because this line echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));exit(); is not refreshing the page again. Where I initially had header.

Comment: ok does it comes in the success function of ajax please put an alert at here `if(data.success==1){alert('something');  location.reload();}`

Comment: So I guess you are aware that I am using a while loop to display datas from table, it's like posts. so the problem is only first post link is clickable. other than that other links are not functioning. Also if I remove if(data.success==1). The page is loading and changes are occuring successfully. but again this is only for first post. rest not working.

Comment: ok i got your problem we cannot use same id on more than one div so you have to do this by class change it like this `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ajax_reload" data-key="some_value" data-someval="1">Unfollow</a>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.ajax_reload').on('click',function(){`

Answer (score 0):

To have your redirected page scroll down to the initial location, include a fragment (#) at the end of the location header:

```
if(isset($_GET['key']) && isset($_GET['val'])){
            //some task....
            header('location:home.php#ajax_reload"'); 
}
```

Comment: Yes I am really sorry to not have added this in my question. I am using php to show bunch of datas on my page from mysql database. hence all datas have same id and class.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple solution to this would be to build the link with a tag, and add the tag in the HTML, for example:

```
<a href="home.php#LinkThisPartOfThePage?key=some_value&val=1" id="ajax_reload">Unfollow</a>
<div name="LinkThisPartOfThePage">...</div>
```

Now your link will point to that particular `div`

Comment: Yes I am really sorry to not have added this in my question. I am using php to show bunch of datas on my page from mysql database. hence all datas have same id and class. I have added this in quetion too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action in PHP without reloading the page, a solution is by using ajax.

Example :

**Html :**

```
<a href="#" id="ajaxButton">Click !</a>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$("#ajaxButton").on('click', function() {
   var btn = $(this);
   $.ajax({
        url : 'phpscript.php?key=somevalue&val=1',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json', 
        success : function(dataObject, statut){ 
            // some tasks ...
            console.log(dataObject);
        },

        error : function(result, statut, error){
            console.log(erreur);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['key']) && isset($_GET['val'])){
        //some task....
        return json_encode($result);
    }
?>
```

This way the return of the PHP is use with javascript withount any reloading

Comment: this code is very similar to one by nikita. But I cannot use this code since key and val is used in javascript here. But i am extracting them in loop from database where a tag is given. Thanks for your time and help.